# Why is this query really slow with 70k+ rows?

Tags: mysql

First of all, this is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_forum_comments` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`forum_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`data` int(11) NOT NULL,
`comment` longtext NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Before importing my backup, it had like 10-15 rows and I made a ranking system based on number of comments and this query was working flawlessly:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(f.id) AS rank 
FROM site_users AS u 
LEFT JOIN site_forum_comments AS f ON (f.user_id = u.id)
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY rank DESC 
LIMIT :l
```

But now, with more than 70k rows inserted, the script won't even load and just crashes the server.

What have I possibly done wrong? Is this problem about the query specifically or is it the table structure?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: If you run the query by hand via mysql cli or other client, doe the query run and finish in reasonable time?  What is the error in your php_error.log... I bet it's a memory allocation error.

Comment: `SELECT u.id, u.user_id,...` There is `site_user.id` as well as a `site_user.user_id` ?  That seems odd.

Comment: Use the explain place to work out what is going on

Comment: Ray has a good question.  Also, adding in some indexes might help your cause.  The PK on the table is automatically indexed, but adding an index for username and/or the id/username combo might help the cause.

Comment: Let me clear things up: I'm running this in a php script within PDO, the LIMIT is 5 results by the way. About "u.user_id", mistyped, sorry, its u.username.

Comment: I am a noob in MySQL but can it be that the query is slow because there is no index on user_id? You could drop the join directly select Form the comments table or? But I would suggest to add a comment_count column in your user table if you want the fastest performance

Comment: comment_count seems odd to me, I would have to update it frequently whenever I update the table or something like that. Also, I would have to add columns to all of my different website areas such as news and interviews

Comment: Jea that's right you need to update it. But its not odd. For example I guess stack overflow has a column with reputation. Althought it could also always sum it up every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(f.id) AS rank 
FROM site_users u LEFT JOIN
     site_forum_comments f
     ON f.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id 
ORDER BY rank DESC 
LIMIT :l
```

Because you are choosing the highest ranked user, you can probably use an inner join rather than an outer join.  In any case, this version doesn't have a great many optimization opportunities.  But, you need an index on `site_forum_comments(user_id, id)`.

You might get better performance with the same index and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM site_forum_comments f
        WHERE f.user_id = u.id
       ) as rank
FROM site_users u 
ORDER BY rank DESC 
LIMIT :l;
```

Comment: While indexing was keen to solve the problem, I couldn't really notice much differences in terms of performance between those two queries. Are subqueries faster than join constructions?

Comment: @MateusMelo: a naive, not very optimized, implementation of your JOIN query might have instantiated the JOIN as a temporary table, and

Comment: @MateusMelo . . . Under some circumstances the correlated subquery can be faster because of how MySQL implements aggregations.  That is not always the case, so it is worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently joining all users to their comments without an index on the user_id column thats slow.

The following  query will select the highest user first and only join that one user with the highest rank with the `site_users` table (using the index over `site_users.id`). So it should be faster.

```
SELECT site_users.id, site_users.username, a.rank
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as rank
    FROM site_forum_comments
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY rank DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS a 
LEFT JOIN site_users ON a.user_id = site_users.id
```

note that with this query you won't get a result if the rank is 0